# How to link library using cmake

Tags: c++, c, unix, cmake, compilation

I need to use external library in my program. (https://github.com/davidmoreno/onion)
I am new to CMake (and to this way of compiling programs as well).

The library contains `CMakeLists.txt` files, so I guess I should be able to use it.
But when I try to compile, e.g. the hello world program example (/onion/examples/hello/). I get an error that CMake is not able to link (or even find) used libraries like onion.h.

To compile I am creating a subdirectory "build" from which I execute commands `cmake ..` and then `cmake --build .`

Here are the source files of hello world program. (https://github.com/davidmoreno/onion/tree/master/examples/hello)

CMakeLists.txt:

```
include_directories (${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/) 

add_executable(hello hello.c)
target_link_libraries(hello onion)
```

hello.c (only header):

```
#include <onion/onion.h>
#include <onion/log.h>
#include <onion/version.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

Here is the build output:

```
open# cd build/

open# cmake ..
CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as

    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

  should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may be lower
  if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project.  For more
  information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user1/onion/examples/hello/build

open# cmake --build .
Scanning dependencies of target hello
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/hello.dir/hello.o
/home/user1/onion/examples/hello/hello.c:18:10: fatal error: 'onion/onion.h'
      file not found
#include <onion/onion.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
*** Error 1 in . (CMakeFiles/hello.dir/build.make:63 'CMakeFiles/hello.dir/hello.o': /usr/bin/cc  -I/home/user1/onion/examples/hello/src   -...)
*** Error 1 in . (CMakeFiles/Makefile2:68 'CMakeFiles/hello.dir/all')
*** Error 1 in /home/user1/onion/examples/hello/build (Makefile:84 'all')
```

I have tried many solutions but none worked to me.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in your question. Avoid links to external sites since they may change or get removed in the future.

Comment: Yup, you are right. I've added both source files.

Comment: Which language, C **or** C++, as they are two distinct languages?  The C++ allows for overloading of functions and operators.  The compiler may use *name mangling* when dealing with libraries.

Comment: Hi Thomas, this example is in C but there is C++ example where I had same problem.

Comment: `No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as

    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

  should be added at the top of the file` From the readme `if you want to use the examples on your instalation, compile and __install__ libonion for the current system first.` Did you installed libonion for you current system first?

Comment: Thanks, apparently I've missed that part with libonion ... I though libonion is the same as onion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this repository setup, you should be compiling this example by using the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file in the repository, ***not*** by running CMake on the file in the `/onion/examples/hello/` directory. By running from the top-level, you have the option to include all examples (they are enabled by default).

By running CMake from the `/onion/examples/hello/` directory, the `include_directories()` command resolves *relative* to the current directory. This is evidenced by the "include" line in your compilation stream here:

```
-I/home/user1/onion/examples/hello/src
```

The `hello` example points to `<onion/onion.h>`, but header files do not exist here in the directory you included. Rather they are here:

```
/home/user1/onion/src/onion/onion.h
```

So, the easiest way to fix the issue would be to compile your example by running your `cmake` command from the **root** of the repository.

Comment: Hi, I did that (cmake from the root directory + cmake --build) but now I am getting another error after trying to run the program.   

open# ./examples/hello/hello   

assertion "("libev: ev_loop recursion during release detected", loop_done != EVBREAK_RECURSE)" failed: file "ev.c", line 3570, function "ev_run"
Abort trap (core dumped)

Comment: @Chody123 It sounds like you got everything to build. This new issue sounds like a separate problem entirely, for which you should post a new question. On Stackoverflow, we aim for a focused, pointed Q&A environment; if you post the new issue as a separate question, it will get more visibility and someone will be more likely to help. Also, if you thought my answer was helpful, you should mark it as accepted.